# Color-changing Button

Tags: javascript

I am making a 3-color button that switches between red, green, and blue when you hit it. I think the error is in this

```
if (color.style.backgroundColor == 'ff0000';) {
            color.style.backgroundColor='00ff00';
        }
        if (color.style.backgroundColor == '00ff00';) {
            color.style.backgroundColor='0000ff';
        }
        if (color.style.backgroundColor == '0000ff';) {
            color.style.backgroundColor='ff0000';
        }
```

code, but I don't know what the specific problem is.

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Button</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function buttonpress() {
    alert("Hi");
}
function colors() {
    if (color.style.backgroundColor == 'ff0000';) {
        color.style.backgroundColor='00ff00';
    }
    if (color.style.backgroundColor == '00ff00';) {
        color.style.backgroundColor='0000ff';
    }
    if (color.style.backgroundColor == '0000ff';) {
        color.style.backgroundColor='ff0000';
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="buttonpress()">Click Me</button>
<p></p>
<button id="color" onclick="colors()">Hi</button>
<script>
color.style.backgroundColor='ff0000';
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Also, just as a tip you are slightly missing the capabilities of javascript which could greatly improve the flexibility of your code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Button</title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="color1">Hi</button>
<button id="color2">Hi</button>
<button id="color3">Hi</button>
<button id="color4">Hi</button>
<button id="color5">Hi</button>
<script type="text/javascript">

function BgColorChanger(elem) {

    this.nextColor = function() {
        ++index;
        if (index == colors.length)
            index = 0;

        elem.style.backgroundColor = colors[index];
    }

    elem.onclick = function() {
        changer.nextColor();
    }

    var changer = this;
    var colors = ['ff0000', '00ff00', '0000ff'];
    var index = -1;

    this.nextColor();

}

new BgColorChanger(document.getElementById("color1"));
new BgColorChanger(document.getElementById("color2"));
new BgColorChanger(document.getElementById("color3"));
new BgColorChanger(document.getElementById("color4"));
new BgColorChanger(document.getElementById("color5"));

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Using the above code you can now color change unlimited elements without writing more code. Additionally if you keep reference to the BgColorChanger instance, external code could change the color by calling bgColorChangerInstance.nextColor();

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `else`. Otherwise, after you change the color in the first `if`, it then matches the second `if` and gets changed again, and then it matches the third `if` and gets changed back to the first color.

You had an extra `;` in your `if` statements.

When you read a color style, it returns the color in `rgb()` format, not hex code (but I've read that old versions of IE don't do this).

When you set the style using hex codes, you must have a `#` prefix.

```
function colors() {
    if (color.style.backgroundColor == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)') {
        color.style.backgroundColor='#00ff00';
    }
    else if (color.style.backgroundColor == 'rgb(0, 255, 0)') {
        color.style.backgroundColor='#0000ff';
    }
    else if (color.style.backgroundColor == 'rgb(0, 0, 255)') {
        color.style.backgroundColor='#ff0000';
    }
}
```

Another way to do it is with `switch/case`:

```
function colors() {
    switch (color.style.backgroundColor) {
    case 'rgb(255, 0, 0)':
        color.style.backgroundColor='#00ff00';
        break;
    case 'rgb(0, 255, 0)':
        color.style.backgroundColor='#0000ff';
        break;
    case 'rgb(0, 0, 255)':
        color.style.backgroundColor='#ff0000';
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/64Bvc/11/)

Answer (score 0):

Several issues

- Missing the opening `<script>` tag
- Do not end the if statements with a semicolon, syntax error
  eg

you code

```
 if (color.style.backgroundColor == 'ff0000';) {
        color.style.backgroundColor='00ff00';
 }
 if (color.style.backgroundColor == '00ff00';) {
        color.style.backgroundColor='0000ff';
 }
 if (color.style.backgroundColor == '0000ff';) {
        color.style.backgroundColor='ff0000';
 }
```

should be

```
if (color.style.backgroundColor == 'ff0000') {
        color.style.backgroundColor='00ff00';
    }
    if (color.style.backgroundColor == '00ff00') {
        color.style.backgroundColor='0000ff';
    }
    if (color.style.backgroundColor == '0000ff') {
        color.style.backgroundColor='ff0000';
    }
```

- The if statements are not exclusive, if the first one matchs and changes the color, then the second one will match and change the color, and then the third one will match and change the color back to the beginning. You need `if else` statements

eg

```
 if (color.style.backgroundColor == 'ff0000') {
     color.style.backgroundColor='00ff00';
 } else if (color.style.backgroundColor == '00ff00') {
     color.style.backgroundColor='0000ff';
 } else if (color.style.backgroundColor == '0000ff') {
     color.style.backgroundColor='ff0000';
 }
```

- The value returned from `style.backgroundColor` isn't always a hex color, it can be `rgb(255,0,0)` so your if statements won't match at all. You can set it this way, but the browser doesn't alwys return in the same format. I would handle it with an additional variable. Instead of checking the element, store and check the variable. Something like

(only as an example, there are numerous ways)

```
var currentColor = 'red';
function colors() {
    if (currentColor == 'red') {
        color.style.backgroundColor='00ff00';
        currentColor = 'green';
    }
    else if (currentColor == 'green') {
        color.style.backgroundColor='0000ff';
        currentColor = 'blue';
    }
    else if (currentColor == 'blue') {
        color.style.backgroundColor='ff0000';
        currentColor = 'red';
    }
}
```